# Translating object attributes to human friendly strings from dictionary tables

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Laptop class for learning purpose and few tables in database: producers, colors, type which are dictionary tables (like ID, Name) and the actual laptop table.

My laptop table looks like this:

```
MODEL | PRODUCER | COLOR | TYPE
-------------------------------
ABC1  |     1    |   2   |   1
XYZ   |     2    |   1   |   1
```

Other tables looks like this (colors table for example):

```
ID | NAME
---------
1  | red
2  | green
```

My class attributes are:
model - string,
producer - int,
color - int,
type - int.

My problem is: when I get laptop objects from db and I want to fill a combo box with them the way I retrieve them isn't really human friendly. I want to translate all those ints to strings from db to get something like this.

ABC1 - DELL - BLACK - STANDARD - 30$

How to approach this problem? Special methods? Special class? I hope I explained it good enough. Thanks.

EDIT

Ok so to be clear when I get my laptop object from I use simple select query `select model, producer, color, type from laptop`
And as result I get a row with a model string and the rest of attributes as ints and then I create a object. If use join `select laptop.model, producer.name, color.name, type.name from ... laptop join producer on laptop.producer = producer.id ...` etc
What I get as result of this is all strings which doesn't match my class structure.
What is a good practice to approach this?

Comment: Look at keywords like `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` and such. It's hard to give you a full answer. I can try but that will leave you with a concrete solution (not sure if even that since you didn't detail the structure of the rest of your table) but the best is that you learn the usage of these keywords and T-SQL syntax and be able to do everything you want. Good luck!

Comment: You can use enums to still save numbers in your database and show user-friendly literals for the users.

Comment: I know I have to use joins, the problem is that with structure of my class (mostly ints), where should I store string that I get from my join statement?

Comment: You can't. Not in this class. You should either expand it to hold string values, or use other classes that hold both ID and string values and link to them in your code (i.e. in your "main" class make a member variable that is of type of one of the "child" classes) or make a whole new class that is your "View Model" or "DTO" that will hold these "rendered" joins.

Comment: @OferZelig Hey, you mean that I should just add some string attributes to the same class and use them or extend original class with a class "LaptopString" (feels kinda wrong)? Is adding additional string attributes a good practice while leaving old integer attributes empty?

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of ways you could do this. For example you could join the dictionary tables in to just return the columns that you want, e.g. the color's name instead of it's ID. Or you could lazy evaluate, e.g. have a get method for colorName which retrieves the value for that one row from the database. Lazy evaluation can impact performance badly though, so you could retrieve the dictionary tables into a Dictionary or the equivalent and look them up in memory.